# Failed to create user namespace

Tags: containers, singularity-container, nextflow

I installed singularity and nextflow in a docker image, I wanted to launch the singularity pcm image, with this command :

```
nextflow pcm.nf --allow-setuid --in example/example_proteome.faa --out result -w work/ -with-singularity pcm_202010.img
```

Please i don't understand this error.

Thanks for your help

```
 N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
    Launching `pcm.nf` [jolly_joliot] - revision: 3402118766
    executor >  local (1)
    [68/112863] process > convert_names (1)          [  0%] 0 of 1
    [-        ] process > index_query                -
    executor >  local (1)
    [68/112863] process > convert_names (1)          [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
    [-        ] process > index_query                -
    Project : /opt/progs/pcm
    Cmd line: nextflow pcm.nf --allow-setuid --in example/example_proteome.faa --out result -w work/ -with-singularity pcm_202010.img
    Oops .. something went wrong
    Error executing process > 'convert_names (1)'
    
    Caused by:
      Process `convert_names (1)` terminated with an error exit status (255)
    
    Command executed:
    
      convert_names.py -i example_proteome.faa -o conv_name.fasta -a association.tsv
    
    Command exit status:
      255
    
    Command output:
      (empty)
    
    Command error:
      INFO:    Converting SIF file to temporary sandbox...
      FATAL:   while extracting /opt/progs/pcm/./pcm_202010.img: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : Failed to create user namespace: not allowed to create user namespace
      : exit status 1
    
    Work dir:
      /opt/progs/pcm/work/68/112863a3adddbb02900a892952162d
    
    Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

Comment: This isn't a Nextflow problem. You should be able to reproduce the error independently of Nextflow with something like: `docker run --rm <your_container> bash -c 'singularity exec /path/to/pcm_202002.img ls -l /usr/local/bin'`. I suspect the error has something to do with how Singularity has been installed inside the container, but it's difficult to say what the solution is without the Dockerfile...

Answer (score 3):

To be able to run Singularity from inside a Docker container, you must use the `--privileged` flag when starting it.

ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities